# WPFDataGrid, how to switch all single row cells into edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, usability

I am using standard WPF DataGrid. When user double clicks (or F2) on some cell, the cell switches to edit mode - displays input filed.

Is there a way to switch all cells in the current row into edit mode when user starts editing one of the cells?

If this is not possible, is there some workarounds on how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by switching all cells to edit mode?

Comment: I am trying to achieve behavior required by my customer. It is very uncomfortable for user to double click or F2 or tab to switch the cell before it can edit a value. For example, to select something from combo box, it first needs to activate cell and then when combo appears to click on the arrow and select item. Very bad!

Comment: Please provide your xaml. I have some thoughts on way it may be achieved. Are you're using `DataGrid.CellEditingTemplate`?

Comment: Grid is built totally in code not in xaml and it is using CellEditingTemplate. I know that there is a some kind of solution using both display and editor in the CellTemplate and then switching their visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're looking for: [DataGrid Tips & Tricks: Single-Click Editing](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing)